# Animate.css does not seem to work with Laravel 7.10.3 in Chrome and FF

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, animate.css

I am trying to use [Animate.css](https://github.com/animate-css/animate.css) in my Laravel project. I installed Animate.css using the following command:

```
npm install animate.css --save
```

I included it in \resources\sass\app.scss file:

```
@import "~animate.css/animate.css";
```

Then I ran the following npm command to compile it into app.css:

```
npm run dev
```

When I look into the page source in the browser, animate.css seems to be included but the HTML elements are not animated. Animation seems to be working in Edge but not in Chrome (v81.0.4044.138) or FF (v76.0).

Comment: check the latest documentation.they have changed the class structure from the latest version onwards. maybe that's the issue. https://animate.style/#migration

Comment: Thank you for the comment, latest documentation helped resolve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have either forgot the JavaScript or didn't configure things correctly. First, install animate.css.

```
npm i animate.css --save
```

In bootstrap.js, add `'animate.css'`.

```
window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.animate = require('animate.css');
```

In app.scss:

```
@import "~animate.css/animate";
```

Create a production-ready build.

```
npm run prod
```

Then make sure you are using the correct files.

```
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this information Karl, It so helpful in my new Laravel project.

Comment: FYI, check with changing version as well.